# How to get all WooCommerce product attributes taxonomies slugs and names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, custom-taxonomy

In WooCommerce I am trying to add a custom field to all of product attributes as a plugin…

For the moment in the code below, I am able to add a custom field to one taxonomy:

```
function pippin_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
// this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
?>
<div class="form-field">
    <label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'pippin' ); ?></label>
    <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="">
    <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','pippin' ); ?></p>
</div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'pa_flavor_add_form_fields', 'pippin_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );

// Edit term page
function pippin_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {

// put the term ID into a variable
$t_id = $term->term_id;

// retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
$term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" ); ?>
<tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'pippin' ); ?></label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) : ''; ?>">
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','pippin' ); ?></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
add_action( 'pa_flavor_edit_form_fields', 'pippin_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );
```

How to get all WooCommerce product attributes taxonomies slugs (and names)?

This way I could make those custom fields dynamically for all existing product attributes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get product attribute taxonomy **slugs** (and taxonomy **names**) by using:

1. Before WooCommerce version 3.6 with [`wc_get_attribute_taxonomies()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_attribute_taxonomies.html) dedicated function:

   ```
    // Get an array of product attribute taxonomies slugs
    $attributes_tax_slugs = array_keys( wp_list_pluck( wc_get_attribute_taxonomies(), 'attribute_label', 'attribute_name' ) );

    // Get an array of product attribute taxonomies names (starting with "pa_")
    $attributes_tax_names = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_attribute_taxonomy_name', $attribute_taxonomies ));
   ```
2. Since WooCommerce version 3.6+  with [`wc_get_attribute_taxonomy_labels()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_attribute_taxonomy_labels.html) dedicated function:

   ```
    // Get an array of product attribute taxonomies slugs
    $attributes_tax_slugs = array_keys( wc_get_attribute_taxonomy_labels() );

    // Get an array of product attribute taxonomies names (starting with "pa_")
    $attributes_tax_names = array_filter( array_map( 'wc_attribute_taxonomy_name', $attribute_taxonomies ));
   ```

Official documentation:

- All WooCommerce related product attribute functions: [`wc-attribute-functions.php` core file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php)
- WordPress: [`wp_list_pluck()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/)
- PHP functions: [`array_keys()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Comment: You should correct the variables $attribute_taxonomies with $attributes_tax_slugs